# asp.net web forms (VB) page rendering incorrect data from SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, translation

I have a web forms app (asp.net / VB) that translates the labels on the page into the users chosen language (stored in SQL). The translations are stored in SQL and the labels on each page are populated on page load. This has worked perfectly for years but more recently we have had an increase of users and multiple languages on the system.

Recently some users are experiencing an issue where the incorrect language is displayed on page load (with quite a lot of labels on it), or when performing a post-back. It has been very difficult to diagnose, but I now believe the IIS server is rendering the incorrect information as 2 users are loading the page at exactly the same time, and whoever clicks it first sets the language for both. For example:

User 1 (English) | User 2 (German)

User 2 loads the page a few milliseconds before User 1, so both users see German text. As soon as User 1 refreshes the page or performs a post back, the correct language is displayed until they navigate away from the page and then return. This doesn't happen every time and the only way I can replicate it, is to have two separate computers and click the links at the same time.

Pseudo Code:

myLabel.Text = SELECT TranslationText from MultiLingual WHERE CtrlID = @CtrlID AND LanguageID = @LanguageID

Does anybody have any experience with something similar or able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

**The Main Page Load Code calls the following:**

```
CLib.MultiLingualLanguage = CLib.GetUserDefaultLanguage(CInt(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
```

**CLib Class Code related to the above:**

```
Public Shared Sub SetMultiLingualText(ByVal Page As Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In Page.Controls

            ' === 
            Dim controlId As String = Trim(UCase(ctrl.ID))
            If Len(controlId) > 0 Then
                If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
                    ' === Apply text to labels specifically wanting dynamic text
                    If controlId.StartsWith("LBL_DB_") Then
                        CType(ctrl, Label).Text = labelText(controlId)
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Literal Then
                    If controlId.StartsWith("LIT_DB_") Then
                        CType(ctrl, Literal).Text = labelText(controlId)
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is LinkButton Then
                    ' === Apply text to buttons specifically wanting dynamic text
                    If controlId.StartsWith("LBTN_DB_") Then
                        CType(ctrl, LinkButton).Text = labelText(controlId)
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
                    ' === Apply dynamic text to all buttons that do not start with BTNDT (Button, no dynamic text)
                    If controlId.StartsWith("BTN_DB_") Then
                        CType(ctrl, Button).Text = labelText(controlId)
                    End If
                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is ListView Then
                    ' === Apply dynamic text to all buttons that do not start with BTNDT (Button, no dynamic text)
                    SetMultiLingualText(ctrl)
                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is ListViewItem Then
                    ' === Apply dynamic text to all buttons that do not start with BTNDT (Button, no dynamic text)
                    SetMultiLingualText(ctrl)
                End If

            End If
            ' === 
            ' === Recurse through controls that may contain other controls (e.g. a form)
            ' === 
            If ctrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                SetMultiLingualText(ctrl)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


Public Shared Function labelText(ByVal CtrlID As String) As String
    Dim controlText As String = ""
    If Len(Trim(CtrlID)) > 0 Then
        If Len(Trim(MultiLingualLanguage)) < 1 Then MultiLingualLanguage = "en-gb"

        Dim dbConn As SqlConnection = getOpenSqlConnection()
        Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand(" SELECT CtrlText FROM MultiLingual WHERE CtrlID = @CtrlID AND LanguageCode = @MultiLingualLanguage", dbConn)
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CtrlID", CtrlID)
        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MultiLingualLanguage", MultiLingualLanguage)
        Dim textText As String = myCmd.ExecuteScalar & ""
        '  === 
        If Len(Trim(textText)) > 0 Then
            controlText = textText
            'rStr = "!" & textText
        Else
            controlText = "?" & Replace(CtrlID, "_", " ") & "?"
            Dim cmdText As String = " INSERT INTO MultiLingual (CtrlID, LanguageCode, CtrlText) "
            cmdText &= " SELECT @CtrlID, @MultiLingualLanguage, @controlText "
            cmdText &= " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM MultiLingual WHERE CtrlID = @CtrlID AND LanguageCode = @MultiLingualLanguage) "
            myCmd = New SqlCommand(cmdText, dbConn)
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CtrlID", CtrlID)
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MultiLingualLanguage", MultiLingualLanguage)
            myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlText", controlText)
            myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
        dbConn.Close()
    End If
    'End If
    ' === 
    Return controlText
End Function
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but is it maybe possible that you're storing informations (like the `LanguageID`) in properties / fields that are `static`?

Comment: Shared variables? Output cache? With the current state of your question, we can only guess. You need to post some relevant parts of the code.

Comment: @bassfader - interesting - please can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @James Anything that is `static` will be "shared" in the entire AppDomain. Since the application is hosted in IIS using a single AppDomain, this means that any user of your site will basically "work in the same AppDomain" as any other user, and therefor anything stored in `static` fields / properties will be shared for all users. Because of this `static` should be used with great care in general in applications handling multiple users at once (like most ASP.NET projects).

Comment: Code added for clarity